# Converting column to list and then to column with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I want to reduce the number of repeat rows I have in my data frame from this

[image]

to this

[image]

I do this with this code

```
exons=cnvs.groupby (['Gen','Transcript_ID', 'CNV_TYPE','oe_lof_upper_e','oe_lof_upper_bin_e')['Exon_rank_in_transcript_e'].apply(list)
```

However, the last column has no column name, I would like to conver the results of this list in a proper column, keeping the structure of the current ouput. How can I do this?

(I know put images is not the best practice but I am working in a HPC and I cannot copy and paste from that to internet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `name` parameter:

```
exons=cnvs.groupby (['Gen','Transcript_ID', 'CNV_TYPE','oe_lof_upper_e','oe_lof_upper_bin_e')['Exon_rank_in_transcript_e'].apply(list).reset_index(name='LIST')
```